# How to put timer in AlertDialog.Builder in android&?

Tags: android, timer, textview, android-alertdialog

I created an AlertDialog. And I need to put a timer there somehow.
Timer must show time from 90 seconds to 0 seconds.

Does someone know how to make that inscription in textView("90 sseconds to acceptance...") change every second with different text? ("90 sseconds to acceptance..." -> "89 sseconds to acceptance..." -> etc..)

[image: timer should look like that]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
/*
new CountDownUpdate((TextView)findViewById(R.id.accept_text), 90, 
    new CountDownUpdate.Callback(){
        @Override
        public void onCountDownComplete(TextView textView)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "BOOM!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
*/
private static class CountDownUpdate implements Runnable
{
    private Callback mCallback;
    private int      mFrom;
    private TextView mView;


    public CountDownUpdate(TextView view, int from, Callback callback)
    {
        mCallback = callback;
        mFrom     = from;
        mView     = view;
        mView.post(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        mView.setText(mFrom + " seconds to acceptance...");
        if(mFrom-- == 0){
            if(mCallback != null){
                mCallback.onCountDownComplete(mView);
            }
        }
        else{
            mView.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    }

    public static interface Callback
    {
        public void onCountDownComplete(TextView textView);
    }
}
```